# How to transform all data in sheet to values - google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was trying to find a solution for the following:

There are several sheets where the formulas are used.
The data from these sheets is copied manually into a single "Archive" sheet at the end of the day.
The data in "Archive" should be pasted as values only.
Instead of copy paste as values every time, I was trying to automatize this procedure.

What is the script for transforming automatically the data pasted into "Archive" in values?
It would also be great to have a button to trigger this script.

Can anyone help?

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [help] on how to ask good questions. This question is too broad, you should include your own attempts to solve the problem and indicate one particular problem with them.

Answer (score 0):

To give a global logic.
You should probably look these methods.

```
SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.Sheet.Range.getValues();
```

and

```
SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.Sheet.Range.setValues();
```

If my I'm not mistaken,
this functions should get your datas in 2D Array.
Then paste Them as String in your spreadsheet.

Cheers

Comment: No offense but these methods do not exist like that... but you get the "general idea"...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this has been answered already but since I didn't find it rapidly, I wrote a small example of one of the possible ways to achieve that result : (see comments in code)

```
function createArchive(){
  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();// get current sheet object
  var archive = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().copy('archive of '+currentSheet.getName()).getSheets()[0]; // create a copy and get its first sheet
  var content = currentSheet.getDataRange().getValues();// get the values of the whole current sheet
  archive.getRange(1,1,content.length,content[0].length).setValues(content);// and "paste" it in the copy while preserving initial format (font, colors, borders etc.
}
```